# Try/Catch Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

I want to catch the exception that occurs, when adding a DNS record with `Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA` in PowerShell with the switch `-CreatePTR`, but no reverse lookupzone exists.
But there is no error. If I provoke the error a simple menu pops up and informs me about the situation. But independent from the `-ErrorAction` switch the `$error` variable does not receive an error. What's my fault?

Thanks for your reply.

`PS C:\Users\xyz>> Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "test-mwi4" -IPv4Address 1.1.1.1 -CreatePtr -ZoneName contoso.biz -ErrorAction Continue
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA : Failed to create PTR record. Resource record test-mwi4 in zone mn-man.biz on server MNDEMUCDC010 is created successfully, but corresponding PTR record could not be created.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "test-mwi4" -IPv4Address 1.1.1.1 -CreatePtr - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (test-mwi4:root/Microsoft/...ResourceRecordA) [Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 9715,Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA`

Thank you!

Comment: When you say, you didn't see any error, what did that command do? what was the output/result?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The A-Record was added!

Comment: In this case: `$Error[0].Exception.Message` will give you the error message. Remember that you need to use `-ErrorAction Stop` in-order to make your exception fall in `Catch` block

Comment: `$Error[0].Exception.Message` is empty. I used it like you said!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use this command in try catch block use below code:

```
Try
{
    Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "test-mwi4" -IPv4Address 1.1.1.1 -CreatePtr -ZoneName contoso.biz -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "Error while adding pointer record:`n$($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
}
```

`$Error[0]` returns:

```
$Error[0]
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA : Failed to get the zone information for 
contoso.biz on server HYDLPT487.
At line:3 char:5
+     Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA -Name "test-mwi4" -IPv4Address 1.1.1 ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (test-mwi4:root/Microsoft/...Resou 
   rceRecordA) [Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 1722,Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA
```

Comment: This was my first thought, too. But as I said, the `$error` variable is null. The output from your snippet is just:
`Error while adding pointer record:`

Comment: When you use `-ErrorAction Continue`, nothing will get trapped inside $Error. Just make sure that you have used `-ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: Your error is "failed to get zone information". My error is that no reverse lookup zone exists. But this error is not given to the `$error` variable.